# Returning value from a process creator function in python in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have picked a snippet from http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-examples

```
import multiprocessing
def queue_func(queue):
    for i in range(30):
        time.sleep(0.5 * random.random())
        queue.put(i*i)
    queue.put('STOP')

def test_queue():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=queue_func, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    o = None
    while o != 'STOP':
        try:
            o = q.get(timeout=0.3)
            print o,
            sys.stdout.flush()
        except Empty:
            print 'TIMEOUT'
test_queue()
```

Is it possible to insert a return statement in test_queue() function?

Here's what i wanted to do ... 
Every time a client sends a request, i want to create a new process to handle the backend processing of the individual clients and return the result back to the client. How do i do that? A simple demonstration is highly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, it already has an implicit "return None" at the end, so you can e.g. change that to "return o".

Comment: when i tried to insert a return statement and called the function all i got was
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

'module' object is not callable

Comment: Alright!! it was just an instantiation issue ... sorry to bother you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. You just add a `return whatever` after the while loop.

To get a more useful answer, it's generally a good idea to explain what you want to achieve, what you have tried to achieve that and in what way it didn't work.

Comment: Hey i solved the problem. I just converted my multithreaded program into multiprocessed one. Apparently the system's performance has not changed. Reiterating my problem again: my application is web based, users(there could be many) upload documents using web front end, the system processes the document in the back end & returns the result back to the user. The back end processing can take long(may be 45 secs). Which one's (multi threading/processing) better for my system for handling multiple users? In both cases, longer back end processing also affected the shorter backend processing task.

Comment: @kailashbuki: Multiprocessing is better.